# Include assets in build (SDL-2 game project in C)

Tags: c, codeblocks, assets, sdl-2

I am making game project with SDL-2, coding in C. IDE is Code::Blocks v17.12. I have an issue with my assets folder.

Including assets in the game is no problem. I put them in just like this:

```
SDL_Surface* temp_surface = IMG_Load("assets/player.png");
```

Naturally, this will only work if my project directory has a folder called "assets", which itself has a file called "player.png".

The issue is that this remains the case when the project is build. In my "Release" folder (or wherever I put the build,) "Assets" has to be there, sitting next to the '.dlls' and the '.exe'. This is very sub-optimal. I would not like for a casual user to so easily view the assets of my game.

I have attempted the problem solved by going to Project > Build Settings > Search Directories > Resource Compiler and then adding my assets folder. That did not work, and I'll admit to not knowing what "Resource compiler" actually does, I just took a guess based on the name.

I would be willing to switch to C++, were that to offer the only feasible means of solving this problem. I have not started any projects yet (just scoping out my environment and tools,) and so am willing to change much in order to get the facilities working correctly.

Comment: Easy solution: change your assets' extension into something else for example `.asset`. Another solution is to zip your assets then change `.zip` into `.asset` but you have to figure out to to unzip them before loading them into your game.

Comment: I will admit, I'm surprised the .png still works just fine even when turned into an .asset. I still have to carry the Assets folder around with the .exe to get them to show up on screen, however.

Answer (score 2):

[PhysicsFS](https://icculus.org/physfs/) & binary-embed the resulting archive into your executable using your [favorite method](https://gareus.org/wiki/embedding_resources_in_executables).